# Incremental IDs on Objectify

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

Since upgrading to GAE 1.8, I'm getting scattered ids when annotating with @Id in Objectify:

```
@Id
private Long id;
```

Even though I understand the need for scattered ids in terms of avoiding hotspots on the cloud platform, is there a way in Objectify to get the old incremental ids back? Having to display a hexatridecimal value (like 1DZENH6BSOW) in the UI to avoid that massive generated 64bit id just doesn't cut it.

I'm happy to have a secondary annotation @IdLegacy working in conjunction with the @Id, then @Id will still generate the long id and I can use the legacy id for display purposes.

**SOLUTION:**

Inside my construtor, I have a simple piece of code that allocates an id if ones doesn't exist:

```
if (getId() == null){
    ObjectifyFactory f = new ObjectifyFactory();
    Key<MyEntity> key = f.allocateId(MyEntity.class);
setId(key.getId());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Objectify passes along the App Engine Datastore's scattered id behavior.

A quick check of the Objectify issue tracker doesn't show that anyone has yet made a request for incremental ids. Submit a request to the Objectify devs. http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/issues/list

Comment: Thanks Dave, I'll submit a request.