# get auto-generated id (objectify datastore)

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

i want to pass autogenerated id to 'Name/id' at datastore.can anybody help me for this? here is my code :

```
String Id = "" // i want autogenerated value
```

`profile = new Profile(Id, displayName, mainEmail);`

Id must be autogenerated here. so how to pass it?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to achieve? In the code shown the load method will fetch a profile entity out of the datastore (if one exists with the given key).

Comment: i have edited my question. please have a look and let me know if you can help me for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ObjectifyFactory` has a method `#allocateId()`. You ca find an example usage in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19152016/incremental-ids-on-objectify).

Essentially you do

```
new ObjectifyFactory().allocateId(Profile.class).getId()
```

In case you do not need the id right away I would not use this approach. Just annotate the id with `@Id`, set it to `null` and save the entity. When you do a `ofy().save().entity(...).now()` it will return a `Key` that contains the new id.

Allocating ids via allocated id still performs a datastore request. It will allocate a block of ids of which you will use just one in this case. Use it if you must, don't, if you don't have to.